# LAMP with chrome and max-persistent-connections-per-server

Tags: javascript, php, html, apache, google-chrome

I have a private LAMP server who running indexing php scripts and returns results.

Scripts can be a little long to execute (near 10 minutes).

Users can launch multiple scripts at once. But sometime during indexation ,they have  problem to access the intranet because of browser restrictions.

Under Firefox i can make set , the value of network.http.max-persistent-connections-per-server to users , but is not "user fiendly".

But can't on chrome - (((

For now I have bypassed the problem by configuring lots of private ip addresses on my apache server and doing random on the ip range.

and calling the pages in http: //.10.0.X.X/mapage.php

but this solution does not please me, and it pleases even less the network administrator ;-)

I set "keepalive Off" in my vhost apache but it did not change anything.

i would like to know if anyone would have a solution in the apache configuration , or in php/html/javascript , for resolv the problem.

P.S. my server is private only , i can eventually use solution not used on public apache web server.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: 10.0.0.1 range is local, why not use a cron/scheduled task for this? Your not seriously sitting there clicking refresh after 10mins are you ?

Comment: because i can't make a "global indexation"; i need an "volatile on demand" indexation  on spécific  directory  with spécific parameter.  some directory not local (using some vpn ) ; and   for security reason  only the user who have request an indexation must see the result.... not easy to make with cron....

Comment: other reason is that , one user can make 10 demand of indexation monday at 10pm , and he make 0 demand for the rest of the week.